# Averaging multiple columns inside an SQL table join

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below code is working for me to create a table as below:

```
SELECT reviews.style_id, AVG("col1"), AVG("col2")
  FROM reviews, audios
 WHERE reviews.consumer_id = audios.consumer_id
 GROUP BY style_id
```

[image]

So my issue is that I would like to average `col1` and `col2`, not worrying about NULL values, as they won't exist in my table. However, I do need to maintain the logic of the join. Thanks!

Comment: An unrelated note: you should use explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the implicit ones in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT reviews.style_id,
       (AVG("col1") + AVG("col2")) / 2.0
FROM reviews, audios
WHERE reviews.consumer_id = audios.consumer_id
GROUP BY style_id
```

Comment: I suppose that does the trick assuming the averages for col1 and col2 are based on the same number of rows, which they are. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the Accepted Answer, and based on OP's clarification in comments:

```
SELECT reviews.style_id, 
       Avg((col1+col2)*0.5) 
FROM   reviews 
       INNER JOIN audios 
         ON reviews.consumer_id = audios.consumer_id 
GROUP  BY reviews.style_id
```

This averaging of row-by-row averages of `col1` and `col2` will give the same results.

Comment: I am getting the exact same output table with that query. I want Col1 and Col2 to be averaged together!  Maybe not possible?

Comment: What you want Avg(col1+col2), share the result required.